# Python 2.7 logging via interpreter spawned from CreateProcess

Tags: python, c++, windows, python-2.7, logging

I've read multiple tutorials and HOWTOs on python logging but have still been unable to figure out why my log file isn't getting created (or where it's getting created).

If I run my python source from the windows command prompt ("python myfile.py"), the log file gets created in the same directory as my script.

But... running my script via a C++ CreateProcess call:

```
 STARTUPINFO si;
 PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
 GetStartupInfo(&si);
 TCHAR szCmdLine[] = "\"C:\\python27\\python.exe\" C:\\code\\myfile.py";        
 if (!CreateProcess(NULL, szCmdLine, NULL, NULL, FALSE, NULL, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
```

My C++ application starts and pops up a command window showing output from the process running my python code.  The command window shows logs I've added (streaming to the command window), but I can't find a log file created anywhere obvious.  I'm not sure if it's a windows pathing issue or other modules in my code hijacking the logger file output.  No log file in either the python27 directory, my code directory, or the directory that my C++ exe is running from.

I create the logger instance at the very top of my python source file with:

```
import logging
myLogger = logging.getLogger('myLogger')
myLogger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
fh = logging.FileHandler('myLog.log')
fh.setLevel(logging.INFO)
myLogger.addHandler(fh)
```

And make calls later in the source as such:

```
myLogger.warning('myfile process started %f', time.clock())
```

Any ideas what I'm missing?  Please and thank you.

Comment: It should be in the same directory as the current directory from where you are invoking your C++ based executable. If you want a specific directory for your spawned child, try adding directory path in the 8th parameter to `CreateProcess(..)`.

Comment: Unless it's a simple command-line utility, a program shouldn't log to the working directory, but instead to its own directory in `%LOCALAPPDATA%` (local user) or `%ProgramData%` (locale machine). If `%ProgramData%` is used, when the directory is created the ACL should be extended to give users write and delete access for files, e.g. `subprocess.call('icacls.exe "%s" /grant Users:(OI)(IO)(W,D)' % path)`.

Comment: @SuperSaiyan Thank you!

Comment: @eryksun I'm a bit lost on this suggestion.  I'm still in the development/debugging phase at the moment, just trying to keep everything in one place.  I'll take this into consideration though if I decide to keep the debug logs later.  I'd say I'm almost completely unfamiliar with ACL modification.  If I choose to put debugs logs in a local user directory, I'll need to use the icacls.exe how exactly?  On the interpreter instance or the log file?  If you have any suggested reading on the subject, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Writing to a subdirectory of `%LOCALAPPDATA%` doesn't require modifying the ACL; the user has full control. It's only required when writing to a directory in `%ProgramData%` (local machine application data). A standard user has the right to create files and directories in `%ProgramData%` and gets full control of his or her own files, but the inherited ACL grants only read and execute access to non-admin users. This default won't work if the application expects to write to common data and log files regardless of the current user, so I gave an example that grants users Write and Delete access.

Comment: @eryksun Thank you!